# ExpressionEngine and AngularJS routing

Tags: routing

Does someone already used the AngularJS routing inside EE templates?

Inside common html template the AngularJS routing is working fine, but inside EE templates the routing is not working. What could be the problem?? An .htaccess setting??

thanks,

Stéphane

Comment: Can you give more detail about what "not working" means? Any errors? Can you see what EE URLs are being hit via the browser dev tools?

Comment: Hi Jeremy! no errors,  the segment is not routed inside an EE template, no results, a blank page. And the AngularJs routing it's working fine inside a basic html page with no EE templates. I am a newbie to AngularJS, more practice will help me :)

Comment: Did you manage to work it out? Maybe I can help you out?

Comment: Hi jShadow. Thanks for your reply. If i didn't manage it, but if I need your help, it would be a pleasure!

Comment: Care to post your solution? Could come in handy for others or your future self :)

Comment: I bypass Expression Engine routing all together. I have 1 template in my main.group called index.html. In this I have some ee embeds for the header and footer and my ui-view div (yes, I use ui-router).

Besides the main.group I created a group called api.group. In this group I create templates that output JSON (in combination with the json addon by Rob Sanchez). So getting the data is a breeze! AngularJS retrieves it's data by calling the api.group's template url and it returns JSON so Angular can process the data in it's templates.

It works like a charm!

Comment: nice template solution, i was already using the Rob Sanschez json addon.

Comment: I also starting a project, where EE will serve as a API and Angular on the frond-end with the same plug-in from Rob Sanchez - JSON. I do have however some considerations about the point of the whole thing to be in Angular 1.x rather than following conventional website behavior with EE behihnd it. All this is because:

  - SEO, poor crawlers indexing
  - I can't see any benefits from one-page app as any performance and UX are 100% achievable in traditional way

This is just my opinion off course.